# Cannot acess configration link from admin side in drupal 7.15

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am new to drupal i am trying to configure a gallery module from configuration link from admin but i cannot access that link i got a blank page which shows nothing is that any cache problem in drupal 7 if any please tell me .Please tell me how it happen thanks in advance..

Comment: Blank screen typically means error reporting isn't configured correctly/has been turned off.  See http://drupal.org/node/158043. Consider turning on error reporting to see what the exact error message is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First reflex: `cache clear`

Have a look to the apache logs also

Comment: yes there is no error regarding drupal, also i am working in wamp server